# Yii2 разлогинивание на всех устройствах

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование, yii2, yii

Здравствуйте.
Есть проект на Yii2 фреймворке и там нужно сделать так чтоб при выходе пользователя на одном устройстве/браузере его авторизация слетала абсолютно везде.
Я покопался и увидел что сессии сохраняются в базе данных, и при выходе пользователя очищается сессия которая привязана к этому пользователю.
Как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Аутентификация в Yii2 работает не только через сессии. Еще есть кука `\yii\web\User::$identityCookie`. Если сессия удалена, или протухла по времени, то фреймворк восстановит пользовательскую аутентификацию через эту самую куку. То есть, в первую очередь, нужно сбросить куку.

За валидацию пользовательских cookie отвечает `\yii\web\IdentityInterface::getAuthKey`. На стороне БД обычно это поле `auth_key` в таблице `user`. Его содержимое нужно перегенерить новым случайным значением.

А, затем, если в вашем случае сеcсии хранятся в базе данных, удалить все сесcии конкретного пользователя. Для этого таблица с сессиями должна иметь поле с пользовательским ID.

Если используются встроенные сессии, то это можно не делать. Сессия и сама протухнет достаточно быстро.

Comment: не работает, для одного пользователя создается несколько сессий

Comment: Должно работать. Инвалидируем пользовательские куки + удаляем пользовательские сессии = профит.

Comment: Можно пример плиз, спасибо!